# ListView : Fetch data from selected item

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created a listview and populated it using datatable..
All worked fine...
 Now I added checkbox to all items..
Now I want like when the last column's value of an item is "true" then the checkbox of the same item is checked.

I tried the following code...

```
If LstViewHelp.Items.Count <> 0 Then
    For Each item As ListViewItem In LstViewHelp.Items
        If LstViewHelp.FocusedItem.SubItems(10).Text = "True" Then
            LstViewHelp.FocusedItem.Checked = True
        End If
    Next
End If
```

I am getting the following error object reference is not set to an instance.
Tried many links but no proper solution found...!

Comment: Using `DataGridView` for such requirement would be much better. You can simply assign the data table to `DataSource` of `DataGridView` and show `CheckBox` for boolean columns.

Comment: Your iterator variable is `item` use than instead of `FocusedItem` if you want to act on all items.  A `DataGridView` would be more appropriate

Comment: Actually I am reusing listview, I have created many things like search records and all in this form and using this from different forms... Its like a help form for other forms... I read the internet and some suggested for datagridview but the problem is I have to write same long codes for DataGridView... help in Listview would be a better option for me for now.... @RezaAghaei

Comment: I tried focuseditem even, it gives me index out of range exception... I probably cannot use datagridview for now, for reason, see my reply to RezaAghaei @Plutonix

Comment: The code loops thru all the items using `item As ListViewItem` but it never uses it! There can very easily be no `FocusedItem` which will cause the exception.  The post says you have `listview and populated it using datatable` - in that case populating a DGV would be one line of code.

Comment: You are correct that datagridview will take few lines but some of the settings which I did to the listview have to be done with datagridview and I have to rewrite some sort of code again... I am thinking to switch in datagridview now but still seeking for an option through which my work can be done.. thanx anyways... @Plutonix

Comment: In above code just replace `LstViewHelp.FocusedItem` by `item` as mentioned by Plutonix.

Comment: Okay I try... @RezaAghaei

Answer (score 0):

You can get all selected index like `ListView.SelectedIndexCollection` using `SelectedIndices` . Add `ForEach` loop on selected indexes and edit your SubItem.

```
Dim indexes As ListView.SelectedIndexCollection = Me.ListViewHelp.SelectedIndices

For Each index In indexes
     If Me.ListViewHelp.Items(index).SubItems(10).Text = "True" Then
        LstViewHelp.Items(index).Checked = True
    End If

Next
```

And if you want to check all items you can use `for` loop

```
For i = 0 To Me.ListViewHelp.Items.Count - 1

          If Me.ListViewHelp.Items(i).SubItems(10).Text = "True" Then
            LstViewHelp.Items(i).Checked = True
          End If
Next
```

Comment: Okay, the trigger is not entering in the loop.. I have more then 100 records in listview.

Comment: 100 selected record? Indexes is a collection of selected index. You want do it on all of listview?

Comment: not selected records, just total items is 100 approx with each item of 10 column... My multiselect is false and fullrowselect is true

Comment: I wrote that code when it fill the data from the data table to listview.

Comment: I just want that it check all item's 10th column whether its true or false and check or uncheck the checkbox according to it... I used such logic, maybe its bad but if you have any other logic then share it with me...